# point on curve where tangent line is parallel to another line

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the points on the curve $y=2x^3-3x^2-12x+20$ where the tangent is parallel to the line $y=\sqrt2-12x$

How do I relate parallel line to a tangent line?

Comment: What are some ways to know that two lines are parallel?

Comment: Hint: the derivative gets you the tangent.  Parallel lines have same slope

Comment: my hint: solve $6x^2-6x-12=-12$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=2x^3-3x^2-12x+20$$
Consider a point $(x_0,y_0)$ on this curve. At this point, the slope of the tangent is given by $\frac{dy}{dx}$ evaluated at $x=x_0$.
Therefore,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=[6x^2-6x-12]_{x=x_o}=6{x_0}^2-6{x_0}-12$$
The given line is
$$y=-12x+\sqrt2$$
The slope of this line is clearly $-12$.

Now, two lines $x-y$ plane are parallel if only if they have the same slope.

Thus, for the tangent to be parallel to the given line, its slope must be $-12$.

The problem then reduces to finding the solutions of 
$$6{x_0}^2-6{x_0}-12=-12$$

The values of ${x_0}$ will correspond to the $x$ coordinates of the points satisfying the given condition, and using the equation of the curve, the corresponding values of $y_0$ can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Line slope: $-12$

Curve slope $ = 6 x^2- 6 x -12 $

Can you proceed?